# Why does /#!/ appear on address bar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I've been studying angular 1.5 and using this course

https://thinkster.io/angularjs-es6-tutorial

I've cloned the repo to help me get started and while following the video tutorial, I noticed that my address bar was looking something like this:

http://localhost:4000/#!/

whereas the developer doing the tutorial had /#/ in his address bar.

Why is this the case?

Also im getting these angular ui-router errors:

Error: transition superseded 
Error: transition prevented 
Error: transition aborted 
Error: transition failed

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question for here.  Seems like you should ask the author of the tutorial

Comment: it's got something to do with supporting legacy browsers I believe and is set by default to !

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location read this and the rest of that site ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /#!/ is angular's $location service doing.

Before history.pushState
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

We (The web community) did a workaround where we tracked the window.location.hash most notably twitter.com. now a days http://caniuse.com/#feat=history is supported by all browsers.

So I would suggest to enable html5Mode to use the new history API, which will remove the /#!/
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: i still don't understand. Is it my browser that is doing this.

Comment: Note, that this is my second run of this tutorial.

Comment: The first run, did not have this problem.

Comment: No It's angular that is doing it. I checked the tutorial and html5 mode is commented out. try enabling it by doing $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);